# non ruby travis-ci CLI needed

Tags: travis-ci

I want to use [encryption-keys](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys) on [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/) continuous integration server. [It says](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/#usage) that:

> **The easiest way** to encrypt something with the public key is to use Travis CLI. This tool is written in Ruby and published as a gem.

I have no experience in ruby, and I had problems with installation.

**Is there any other** (non-easiest :) **way to encrypt my passwords/tokens?**

I mean python script, or `curl` commands etc...

Comment: Yes there is a REST API. I believe you have to sign up as a developer to access its documentation though.

Comment: It's probably easier to get the Ruby client working than to write your own from scratch. Are you using it on Windows?

Comment: Maybe youre right, but it seems overkill to install a brand new environment (ie. ruby) just for encrypt some strings